# Group Movable Items in Userform

Tags: excel, vba

After some great assistance from tinman around having multiple images that can be moved over on this questions - [Check if nested control is outside parent control range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619734/check-if-nested-control-is-outside-parent-control-range)

I have now become stuck on trying to achieve a situation where 3 controls are grouped together and all move when one of them is moved.

I have tried using an array as part of the variable declaration but keep getting 'define' errors.

I have considered using a frame but this then creates a situation where the control would need to be able to move outside of the frame and into the main userform which I feel is more complicated from where I am in terms of code currently.

I saw some information about using tags to move all objects with this tag name but this links to the array variable declaration aspect.

If there was a way to set my 'movableimages.image1' variable to contain multiple images, I think this would resolve my problem I just can't work out a way to do it.

**Userform Code**

```
 Option Explicit
    Private MovableImages(1 To 3) As New MoveableImage

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ctrl.Tag = ctrl.Top & "|" & ctrl.Left
    Next
    Call RemoveCaption(Me)
    Image8.Visible = False
    Image11.Visible = False
    Image12.Visible = False
    Image13.Visible = False
    Image14.Visible = False
    Image15.Visible = False
    Label2.Visible = False

   '' Me.StartUpPosition = 0
   '' Me.Top = Application.Top + 400
   '' Me.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - Me.Width - 560
    Set MovableImages(1).Image1 = Image2
    Set MovableImages(2).Image1 = Image3
    Set MovableImages(3).Image1 = Image4
    Set MovableImages(4).Image1 = Image5
    Set MovableImages(5).Image1 = Image6
    Set MovableImages(6).Image1 = Image7
    Set MovableImages(7).Image1 = Image8
    Set MovableImages(8).Image1 = Image11
    Set MovableImages(9).Image1 = Image12
    Set MovableImages(10).Image1 = Image13
    Set MovableImages(11).Image1 = Image14
    Set MovableImages(12).Image1 = Image15


End Sub
```

**Class Module Code**

```
Private Type Coords
    Left As Single
    Top As Single
    x As Single
    y As Single
    MaxLeft As Single
    MaxTop As Single
End Type
Private Image1Coords As Coords

Public WithEvents Image1 As MSForms.Image

Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)

    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        Image1Coords.x = x
        Image1Coords.y = y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    Const PaddingRight As Long = 4, PaddingBottom As Long = 8
    Dim newPoint As Point

    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        Image1Coords.Left = Image1.Left + x - Image1Coords.x
        Image1Coords.Top = Image1.Top + y - Image1Coords.y

        Image1Coords.MaxLeft = Image1.Parent.Width - Image1.Width - PaddingRight
        Image1Coords.MaxTop = Image1.Parent.Height - Image1.Height - PaddingBottom

        If Image1Coords.Left < 0 Then Image1Coords.Left = 0

        If Image1Coords.Left < Image1Coords.MaxLeft Then
            Image1.Left = Image1Coords.Left
        Else
            Image1.Left = Image1Coords.MaxLeft
        End If

        If Image1Coords.Top < 0 Then Image1Coords.Top = 0

        If Image1Coords.Top < Image1Coords.MaxTop Then
            Image1.Top = Image1Coords.Top
        Else
            Image1.Top = Image1Coords.MaxTop
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

For example, when moving image2, Image2 + Image 8 + label1 would all move from their current location by the defined X,Y variable.

Comment: Q: Is `MovableImages` an array? What class is `.Image1` a property of? Are the groups hard-coded or do they need to be flexible to the user?

Comment: So, I just looked at the question you referenced, and this line `Private MovableImages(1 To 3) As New MoveableImage` is declaring MovableImages as an array of MoveableImage objects

Comment: That's alright. What's the maximum number of images you'd have in a group?

Comment: The maximum number of controls in the group would be 3. Two image controls and one label. Do the visible statuses of the controls affect the ability to do this? I.e label1 visible status is triggered by a mousemove event and image2 and image8 visible status it toggled by a dblclick event.

Comment: Would you also want the entire group to move if image8 moved, or only if image2 moves? And the visibility shouldn't matter.

Comment: If it could be done so that the whole group moved if only image2 or image8 moved then that would perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is untested; however, I believe you want something like:

**Class Module**

```
Private Type Coords
    Left As Single
    Top As Single
    x As Single
    y As Single
    MaxLeft As Single
    MaxTop As Single
End Type

Private Image1Coords As Coords

Public WithEvents Image1 As MSForms.Image
Public WithEvents Image2 As MSForms.Image
Public Label1 As MSForms.Label

Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        Image1Coords.x = x
        Image1Coords.y = y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        MoveObject Image1, Image1Coords, x, y
        If Not Image2 is Nothing Then MoveObject Image2, Image1Coords, x, y
        If Not Label1 is Nothing Then MoveObject Label1, Image1Coords, x, y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        Image1Coords.x = x
        Image1Coords.y = y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    Const PaddingRight As Long = 4, PaddingBottom As Long = 8
    Dim newPoint As Point

    If Button = XlMouseButton.xlPrimaryButton Then
        MoveObject Image2, Image1Coords, x, y
        If Not Image1 is Nothing Then MoveObject Image1, Image1Coords, x, y
        If Not Label1 is Nothing Then MoveObject Label1, Image1Coords, x, y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MoveObject(moveObj As Object, moveCoords as Coords, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    Const PaddingRight As Long = 4, PaddingBottom As Long = 8

    moveCoords.Left = moveObj.Left + x - moveCoords.x
    moveCoords.Top = moveObj.Top + y - moveCoords.y

    moveCoords.MaxLeft = moveObj.Parent.Width - moveObj.Width - PaddingRight
    moveCoords.MaxTop = moveObj.Parent.Height - moveObj.Height - PaddingBottom

    If moveCoords.Left < 0 Then moveCoords.Left = 0

    If moveCoords.Left < moveCoords.MaxLeft Then
        moveObj.Left = moveCoords.Left
    Else
        moveObj.Left = moveCoords.MaxLeft
    End If

    If moveCoords.Top < 0 Then moveCoords.Top = 0

    If moveCoords.Top < moveCoords.MaxTop Then
        moveObj.Top = moveCoords.Top
    Else
        moveObj.Top = moveCoords.MaxTop
    End If
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

The Userform module will need to be updated to set `.Image2` and `.Label1`, where needed in the different groups. For example:

```
Set MovableImages(1).Image1 = Image2
Set MovableImages(1).Image2 = Image8
Set MovableImages(1).Label1 = Label1
```

The main differences in the class module are the addition of `Image2` and `Label1`, extracting the moving logic out of the `_MouseMove` event and into a private sub, adding logic into the `_MouseMove` event to move the other two objects as well, and adding the events for `Image2` (similar to `Image1` events with a few differences).